# Identify this "answer waiting" bossa nova song in Russia

Tags: identify-this-sample, identify-this-song

I can't find a full version of this bossa nova song that features in a [Russian comedy show](https://youtu.be/dRxYFh5iFlY?t=77) (only the small piece starting from 1:17).

It looks like Brazilian Portuguese, I hear words (but not sure).

> "você fala para uma americana eu para má o meu coração"

Who knows this song? Please help me to identify.

Comment: I don't know this particular song, but it might help to know that this is Brazilian jazz in the bossa-nova style that was popular in the 60's and 70's.  The joke in the scene appears to be that this kind of music is commonly used in elevators and as "hold" music for telephone services.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This song is called "Palabras." It is by Emanuel Hovaghimian, and was developed specially for the Russian cellphone company "Beeline," which sells it as a "answer waiting" music for cellphones. That's why it is not readily available in open resources. Fortunately it can now be heard here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AjtDBB4SrNw

Comment: That's correct!
We composed the music for beeline in moscow, and beca me a huge hiy in russia.
The track was recorded in buenos aires, Argentina and sung in portuguese
Emanuel

Comment: @Emanuelhovaghimian excellent to see an original artist here!